# How to ad GridView to a GridControl in devexpress?

Tags: gridview, devexpress

I have one GridControl and when I click on run designer it opens a GridView before Main. How to make the same GridView for another GridControl?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the GridView's designer, go to the Layout item in the navbar and save the Layout to an Xml file.  Now, you should be able to open another GridView's Designer and load this layout.